Where are pictures saved when opening the camera from iOS webview?
I have a react native app which uses react-native-webview 13.10.3 (which uses WKWebview on iOS).  Sometimes the page in the webview contains an <input type="file"> which, on click, shows a dialog for selecting a file.  One of the options in this dialog is "Take Photo or Video" which brings up the camera to take a new picture.  The camera goes away after taking a picture, and the <input> gets updated with the details of the newly created image file.
Whenever I go through this process, I notice the size of my app's "Documents & Data" (in Settings > General > Storage > [My App]) increasing by a few MB - about the size of the image file, I believe.  I would like to delete these image files once they are no longer needed in order to keep my app from consuming more and more storage space.
I have read about "Download Container..." available in Xcode > Window > Devices and Simulators.  I looked through my app's container, but I didn't notice any image files.

Temporary files must have been created when you used <input type="file">. I suggest you use react-native-fs library to locate and delete the temp files after the processing is completed or no longer needed.
Like this:
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const deleteTemporaryFiles = async () => {
    try {
        const tempDir = RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath;

        const files = await RNFS.readDir(tempDir);

        for (const file of files) {
          await RNFS.unlink(file.path);
        }

        console.log('Temporary files deleted successfully');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error deleting temporary files:', error);
    }
};

deleteTemporaryFiles();


Thank you @Oladele, I've used react-native-fs to log the files at TemporaryDirectoryPath, and it seems the images are saved at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<some id>/tmp/WKWebFileUpload-<random characters>.
